# Use in, on a list to check one item in tuple

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains tuples and I want to check, if the first value in a tuple contains a specific value.

This is my current solution:

```
cities = [("Hamburg", "Germany"), ("London", "England"), ("Paris", "France")]
for city in cities:
    if city[0] == "Hamburg":
        contains_Hamburg = True
        break
else:
    contains_Hamburg = False
```

If the cities wouldn't store also the country this would look like this:

```
cities_simple = ["Hamburg", "London", "Paris"]
contains_Hamburg = "Hamburg" in cities_simple
```

Is there a way to mix those and use the `in` operator? For example I could do something like this:

```
contains_Hamburg = "Hamburg" in [city[0] for city in cities]
```

But this would create a second list, so I'm hesitant to use this (if python doesn't really create a second list it would be fine, I guess).

Comment: use a dict: `contains_hamburg = "Hamburg" in dict(cities)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close! [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) can be used to check that any of the elements are True. And by using a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) rather than a list comprehension you avoid the additional list cluttering memory.

```
contains_Hamburg = any('Hamburg' in c for c, s in cities)
```

Also you could possible use `==` rather than `in` as below.

```
contains_Hamburg = any('Hamburg' == c for c, s in cities)
```

Comment: Bah, I figured there was no point in both of our answers being here. Although it is faster to do  `c == 'Hamburg' for c, s in cities` rather than accessing indices.

Comment: @Alex ah thanks, didn't think of tuple unpacking making a difference. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if your cities list will be a mix of tuples and strings, as in:

```
cities = [("Hamburg", "Germany"), ("London", "England"), ("Paris", "France"), "Toronto", "Montreal", "New York"]
```

you can have a lambda function to unpack it:

```
city = lambda c: c if type(c) == str else c[0]
```

and use it in a generator:

```
print( 'New York' in (city(c) for c in cities) )
print( 'Paris' in (city(c) for c in cities) )
```

If you are going to use this many times for many cities, it would be worth creating a function like,

```
contains_city = lambda ct: ct in (city(c) for c in cities)

print (contains_city("Moscow")) 
print (contains_city("Toronto"))
```